I am trying to use dynamic SQL query to generate dynamic columns but I received an error in MySQL
I am trying to generate a dynamic column based on the existing projects in my projects table, so I want to collect the user time he spends on each project based on another table that tracks records for users on each project. The problem is when I run the query in MySQL, I received error:    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql  Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM          tracker.team_members tm     JOIN          tracker.teams t ON tm.te' at line 6.
The query:
SET @startDate = '2024-01-01';
SET @endDate = '2024-12-31';

SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
        CONCAT(
            'SUM(CASE WHEN pr.PRJ_NAME = \'', pr.PRJ_NAME, '\' THEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, utt.uttStart, utt.uttEnd) ELSE 0 END) AS `', pr.PRJ_NAME, '`'
        )
    ) INTO @sql
FROM 
    tracker.user_time_tracking utt
JOIN 
    tracker.Projects pr ON utt.prj_Id = pr.prj_id
WHERE utt.utt_Start >= @startDate AND utt.utt_End <= @endDate;

SET @sql = CONCAT('
    SELECT 
        t.name AS TeamName, 
        u.username AS MemberName, 
        p.position_name AS PositionName, 
        ', @sql, '
    FROM 
        tracker.team_members tm
    JOIN 
        tracker.teams t ON tm.team_id = t.team_id
    JOIN 
        Info.Users u ON tm.USR_NAME = u.USR_NAME
    JOIN 
        tracker.Positions p ON u.USR_POSITION_ID = p.POSITION_ID
    LEFT JOIN 
        tracker.user_time_tracking utt ON u.USR_NAME = utt.USR_NAME
    LEFT JOIN 
        tracker.Projects pr ON utt.PRJ_ID = pr.PRJ_ID
    WHERE utt.utt_Start >= \'', @startDate, '\' AND utt.utt_End <= \'', @endDate, '\'
    GROUP BY 
        t.name, u.username, p.position_name
    ORDER BY 
        t.name, u.username;
');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;


Can you help me to solve this error in MySQL, I also want to use it in my spring boot application, and I appreciate any advice on it.
I tried to run the query in MySQL, but I received an error. And when I tried to use select @sql, I received only one column @sql with one record that is the same query. I expect to retrieve a table with a column for member name and his team's name and more columns includes projects columns with the time he spent on each one.
First Result

Second Result


Can you pls share what @sql holds after the first and after the 2nd assignment?

@Shadow I attached images

Thanks for your quick action! Unfortunately, the screenshots are useless as we cannot see the entire content. Please add the full contents as text to the question!

Please add table definitions as text

specifically, table definitions as output from show create table yourtablename, as text

Query the string value of your @sql variable. I predict your query has ... p.position_name AS PositionName, FROM ..., with an errant comma before the FROM, because the first query that fills the pivot-table columns produced no results.
